# how to fix Vue typescript property does not exist error

Tags: vue.js

in vue3 typescript I am having some property does not exist in the HtmlElement error. please help me to solve this issue.

`(property) dataButtons: string`

`(property) data-buttons: string`

`Type '{ class: string; dataButtons: string; "data-buttons": string; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.`

`Property 'dataButtons' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)`

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: This might have been just my situation, but I just solved this sort of issue by restarting the Volar server and quitting/restarting VSCode. You can restart the Volar server from the VSCode command palette (if you're using VS Code)

Answer (score 0):

Providing the code where this issue occurs would help others debug it.

Did you use `ref` on a Vue component?  If so, the result points to the component, not the underlying element.  What you need to do is this:

```html
<template>
  <MyComponent :ref="(c: any) => c?.$el && (myComponent = c?.$el)">
</template>
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const myComponent = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);
</script>
```

The above assumes you are using Vue 3 with the Composition API.